# How to properly join armature to multiple meshes to export a single animation?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, .fbx

I am trying to do a motion capture project where there are many moving empties which contain the animation, and there are bones parented to these empties so that they follow the movement, and small mesh cubes parented to the bones so that the mesh cubes also follow the movement.

When I export it as an fbx, it exports over 100 separate animations, one for each bone. But I want it to just export one animation that is easier to deal with.. is there a way to do this?

Comment: In the Exporter's Bake Animation tab disable "All Actions" and "NLA Strips".

Comment: @FFeller Wow thank u so much! Worked great, I didn't know about those settings before